# MySQL - Finding the position of a record in JOINS

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables namely `registrations` containing users' information, `leaderboard` containing users' ID and the level they are currently on and finally 'clear_times" which records the time when users clear a certain level.

I'm generating a leaderboard using MySQL. User in the highest level will stand on the top. Users in same level will be ranked according to `clear_time`, the time when they have cleared the level. (First to clear the level is ranked ahead).

Following is the code I'm using for the purpose:

```
SELECT t1.level, t3.user_id, t3.user_id2, t3.user_type
FROM leaderboard AS t1
INNER JOIN clear_times AS t2 ON ( t1.uid = t2.uid AND (t1.level -1) = t2.level ) 
INNER JOIN registrations AS t3 ON ( t1.uid = t3.id ) 
ORDER BY t1.level DESC , t2.clear_time ASC
```

`id' is a primary key of and`uid` is a foreign key.

The code works perfect for generating leaderboard. Now, I want to find out the rank of a particular user given his/her `id`. I can this can be done on server-side scripting, looping through the records and using a counter variable. But I believe there is a way of doing this in MySQL itself manipulating in someway the above code, which I couldn't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know the target user's `level` and `clear_time`, you merely need to count the number of records that are ranked higher than that in the given ordering:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   leaderboard   AS t1
  JOIN clear_times   AS t2 ON t1.uid = t2.uid AND t1.level = t2.level + 1
  JOIN registrations AS t3 ON t1.uid = t3.id
WHERE  t1.level > ? OR (t1.level = ? AND t2.clear_time < ?)
```

You can use further joins or subqueries to obtain the missing information about the target user within the same query, if so desired.  I will leave that as an exercise for the reader.