# MySQL: Statement with JOINS doesn't fetch all possible records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[See the scenario here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666653/mysql-finding-the-position-of-a-record-in-joins)

As mentioned in the question I'm using the following MySQL to generate a leaderboard.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.level, t3.user_id, t3.user_id2, t3.user_type 
FROM leaderboard AS t1 
   INNER JOIN clear_times AS t2 
      ON (t1.uid = t2.uid AND (t1.level -1)  = t2.level) 
  INNER JOIN registrations AS t3 ON (t1.uid = t3.id) 
ORDER BY t1.level DESC, t2.clear_time ASC
```

But the problem with the statement is that it is fetching the user records with `level` greater than `1` only. No records with level '1' is being fetched.

Comment: Do you have any records with `level = 0` in the `clear_times` table?

Comment: @Guffa Indeed there is